# How to define Nools in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rules, rule-engine, nools

I am looking to create nools rules in nodejs. I am new to nools rule-engine.I am trying to write a rule but i don't know anything about nools. I have studied whole documentation but it is confusing me. So please can anyone help me
how to create nools rules in server side and how to connect that rules with client side?

Comment: That's depends, what you want to do ?